# For prosseguir se true

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Bom, estou tentando executar vários downloads, um atrás do outro, e gostaria que só começasse o próximo depois que o outro terminar.
Os códigos são esses:

```delphi
  if StrToInt(version) < StrToInt(version2) then
  begin
    for x := StrToInt(version) to StrToInt(version2) do
      url := 'http://pokestage.ddns.net/patch/'+IntToStr(x)+'.rar';
    BaixarArquivo(IdHTTP1, url, x);
  end
  else
    sProgressBar1.Position := sProgressBar1.Max;
  slabel1.caption := '100%';
end;
```

Onde BaixarArquivo retorna true quando o arquivo termina de ser baixado.
Como faço para que só vá para o próximo depois que um for concluido?

Comment: Sim, está executando normalmente, só que ele já começa baixando o último arquivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme seu comentário:

> **Sim, está executando normalmente, só que ele já começa baixando o último arquivo.**

O seu problema está no seu comando `for`.
É uma questão de sintaxe da linguagem **Pascal**, o `Begin` e o `End`.
Como o `{ }` para **php** entre outros.

Por isso da **identação** ser uma coisa importante.
Veja seu exemplo:

```delphi
  if StrToInt(version) < StrToInt(version2) then
  begin
    // o for executa todos os contadores..
    for x := StrToInt(version) to StrToInt(version2) do
      url := 'http://pokestage.ddns.net/patch/'+IntToStr(x)+'.rar'; 

    // quando chegar aqui, a URL será a última --> valor de version2
    BaixarArquivo(IdHTTP1, url, x);
  end
  else
    sProgressBar1.Position := sProgressBar1.Max;
  slabel1.caption := '100%';
end; // <-- sobrando, a princípio
```

Como deveria ser esse laço **for**?

```delphi
for x := StrToInt(version) to StrToInt(version2) do
begin
  url := 'http://pokestage.ddns.net/patch/'+IntToStr(x)+'.rar'; 
  BaixarArquivo(IdHTTP1, url, x);
end;
```

Agora ele gera uma url e passa para o método BaixarArquivo, depois gerará outro, e então passará para o método BaixarArquivo. Assim, sucetivamente.

Como as linhas deveriam ficar:

```delphi
if StrToInt(version) < StrToInt(version2) then
begin
  for x := StrToInt(version) to StrToInt(version2) do
  begin
    url := 'http://pokestage.ddns.net/patch/'+IntToStr(x)+'.rar'; 
    BaixarArquivo(IdHTTP1, url, x);
  end;
end
else
  sProgressBar1.Position := sProgressBar1.Max;

slabel1.caption := '100%';
```

---

#### Sobre os comandos dentro do método `OnTimer` do componente `TTimer`:

Há um detalhe aqui que você precisa saber.

O componente TTimer executará o evento OnTimer de tempos em tempos conforme setado na sua proprieadade Interval.
Logo, como desejado por você na sua última pergunta, é fundamental na primeira linha do método `OnTimer` ter a atribuição do valor **false** para a propriedade do método Enable do componente `TTimer`.

```delphi
procedure Form1.Timer1OnTimer(sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enable := false;

  ... // restante dos seus comandos.
end;
```

Caso você não faça isso, o método OnTimer será executado repetidamente, tentando fazer novamente os comandos de download.
Pelo tempo informado, você pode ter os comandos de download sendo executados novamente antes mesmo de ter terminado a primeira iteração do `for` com o método `BaixarArquivo`.

Espero que isso tenha ficado claro.

Comment: Perfeito, problema resolvido.

Comment: Já tinha feito isso, ficou claro sim.